# How to get all fields in a same level in embedded documents in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

Thanks to embedded documents, we don't need join operations.

However, I need to get all fields in a same level to prepare a list or report.

Are there any easy-way to get all fields in a same level?

For instance; I want to prepare a report with all the following fields. In this case, I need to get all JSON data in a same level.

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "date" : "2014-07-30 02:00",
   "personnel" : {
       "_id": "14",
       "name": "xxxx Stackton",
       "address" : {
             "city": "nevercity",
             "province": "neverland"
              }
     },
    "customer": {
         "_id": "473",
         "name": "xxxx Jordan"
     },
    "payment": {
        "method": "cash",
        "amount": "67.40"
     }
}
```

Comment: The obvious way to do this would be using a [`projection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) to limit the fields returned in your results. For example, to get the address and customer details: `db.data.find({_id: "1"}, { "personnel.address": 1, customer: 1})`. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Stennie, already I am using this way. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the object keys similar like a JSON object

Below sample will print `name` and `age`

```
var myObj = { name : 'Tom', age: 21 };

for(key in myObj) {
  print(key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try at the first opportunity and then I'll inform you.